# Visualizing a (XYZRGBL) .pcd file

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have a 'XYZRGBL' point cloud in a .pcd file. I want to visualize it, so I used this code:

```
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud1, "sample cloud");
  viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "sample cloud");
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
  viewer->initCameraParameters ();
```

But, I received this error:

> no matching function for call to
> ‘pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGBL::Ptr&,
> const char [13])

I tried:

```
viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBL>
```

instead of

```
viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>
```

but still same problem.
Does anyone know where is my fault?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At the end you have to add:

```
while (!viewer->wasStopped ())  {
viewer->spinOnce (100);
boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));  }
```

This will show your Point Cloud.